# Word for an object that undergoes a removal?

Tags: single-word-requests

What would be one word (noun) to describe something that undergoes a removal (has something removed from it)? For example, something that undergoes *multiplication* is a *multiplicand*. Something that undergoes an *absence* is an *absentee*. However neither **removend** or **removee** sound correct.

Examples:

> - The duplicates were removed from the `removend`.
> - I removed 30 objects from the `removend`.

I want to know so I can have better (and more general) variable names than stuff like `list_with_duplicates`.

I'm not looking for the name of the stuff that is removed from the group, I am looking for a word for the group that the objects will be removed from.

Comment: It's not clear **what** undergoes the removal. Generally, the thing removed "undergoes the removal", not what it is removed from, because one says "X **is removed from** Y". However, if you search this site (or elsewhere, but of course I couldn't possibly recommend anywhere better than here!) for *deduplicate* you may find something.

Comment: Your *absentee* example isn't particularly helpful: last I checked the kid who didn't go to school is absent from school, not absent from "absentee". It's relevance to the sentences you have "removend" in is therefore non-existent.

Comment: If you have some doubts on "minuend" that refers to a number rather than a group, you may use, depending on the context, "initial set" or "current set".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The thing from which something is subtracted is the *[minuend](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/minuend)*:-

> The quantity from which another quantity, the subtrahend, is to be
>   subtracted. In the equation 50 - 16 = 34, the minuend is 50. [American Heritage Dictionary]

As explained in the above definition, the thing subtracted is the *[subtrahend](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/subtrahend)*:-

> A quantity or number to be subtracted from another. [American Heritage Dictionary]

So you could say *the duplicates were removed from the minuend*.

Comment: Brian, I shall be forever in your debt for introducing me to these two words, which seem to me to be recondite in the extreme. I am going to attempt to get them into conversation over Christmas dinner though...somehow! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can consider ***redundant***

[redundant](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/redundant)(adj.)

> characterized by verbosity or unnecessary repetition

[Dictionary.com]

or

***superfluous***

[superfluous](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/superfluous) (adj.)

> beyond what is needed : not necessary

[Merriam-Webster]

*Update*

Your examples can be re-written as :

- I removed 30 ***redundant*** objects
- The ***superfluous*** entries were removed.

If you are looking for a noun specifically, **inessential**(in the noun form) could fit the bill, though it may sound a little contrived.

inessential (noun)

> a thing that is not absolutely necessary.

[Source:Google](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=define+inessential&oq=define+inessential&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60.359j0j9&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8)

Thus, you can probably say,

- The duplicates were removed from the ***inessential***.
- I removed 30 objects from the ***inessential***.

Comment: I'm looking for nouns, because I need a word to represent an object, not an attribute.

Comment: I'm looking for a word that represents a group that has objects that will be removed. Inessentials implies that the entire group is composed of inessential objects, which it is not. I'm not looking for a name for what is removed, I'm looking for a name for what they're removed from.

Comment: You are essentially looking for a noun that does not exist. I logically assumed you were going to *remove* a list of objects/entries since they were *unnecessary* and answered

Comment: I would not put "s" after **the essential**. Contrast it with *the young*/*the youngs* should respect *the old*/*the olds*.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of words, but they tend to have connotations attached to specific contexts.  There is **remainder**:

> I smashed the country and western CDs in the music collection, but I still listen to the **remainder**.

In the law, the remainder is what's left of your estate after creditors and the tax man get through with it.  In mathematics, it's what's left over after long division, as in "when you divide 11 by 7, the remainder is 4."

You could use **remnant**, if you don't mind the connotation of the left-over portion being small.  The same with **residue**, which has its use as a term of art in chemistry to designate what's left over after a chemical reaction.  *Residue* also has a definition in the mathematical field of complex analysis.

The word imported from Latin, **residuum**, is a more general term, and the *OED* finds uses of **the residual** as a noun meaning the "product of a residuum.